# How to add newest Akka-HTTP and Akka-stream to build.sbt

Tags: sbt, akka, typesafe-activator, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm using Typesafe/Lightbend Activator, and created a project with 'minimal-akka-scala-seed'. Then I'd changed akka version from 2.3.11 to 2.4.2 (current stable version).
Now I want to add newest stable Akka-HTTP and Akka-stream to my project. What I should write in build.sbt to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the artifacts are no longer marked as experimental, with the `2.4.2` release.

I believe, that the dependency list should look like this:

```scala
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // akka
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.2",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.4.2" % "test",
  // streams
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.4.2",
  // akka http
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-core" % "2.4.2",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-experimental" % "2.4.2",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-testkit" % "2.4.2" % "test",
  // the next one add only if you need Spray JSON support
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json-experimental" % "2.4.2",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test")
```

Comment: Thank you. 
However it is strange that 'akka-http' is still experimental.

Comment: I think this is because there are some possible changes to DSL - check out the release news http://akka.io/news/2016/02/17/akka-2.4.2-released.html

Answer (score 1):

Check this example https://github.com/theiterators/akka-http-microservice. It use newest `akka-http` version